# A counterexample of " If the limit $\lim\limits_{h \rightarrow 0 } \frac{f(x_0 +h) - 2 f(x_0) + f(x_0 -h)}{h^2}$ exists ...

Tags: real-analysis

> Give a counterexample to the following statement " If the limit $$\lim\limits_{h \rightarrow 0 } \frac{f(x_0 +h) - 2 f(x_0) + f(x_0 -h)}{h^2}$$ exists then so does $f''(x_0)$ and they are equal."

I was thinking about $f(x)=x^{4/3}$, where $f'(x)=\frac{4}{9} x^{-\frac{1}{3}}$ where this derivative does not exist at zero.

So according to the statement the following limit should not exist about zero
$$\lim\limits_{h \rightarrow 0 } \frac{f(x_0 +h) - 2 f(x_0) + f(x_0 -h)}{h^2}$$ 
$$\lim\limits_{h \rightarrow 0 } \frac{h^{4/3} + (-h)^{4/3}}{h^2}$$

Comment: Another example:
$$f(x) = \left\{\matrix{1 & x > 0 \\ \frac{1}{2} & x = 0 \\ 0 & x < 0}\right.$$
at $x_0 = 0$.

Answer (score 4):

$f''(x_0)$ can only exist if $f$ is continuous at $x_0$.
Consider
$$f(x)={\bf 1}_{\Bbb Q}(x)-{\bf 1}_{\Bbb Q}(-x) $$
and $x_0=0$.